# How to paste values from batchGet method to google sheet via app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I wrote a script that gets some data from Google Analytics API with batchGet method, that contains 2 dimensions and 3 metrics. However, I don't know how to paste this data to the google sheet. There is the script I wrote, I don't know how to proceed

```
function get_ga(){
  var start_date='2019-04-01';
  var end_date='2019-04-15';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var request = {
    "reportRequests":
  [
  {
    "viewId": '26676016',
    "dateRanges": [{"startDate": start_date, "endDate": end_date}],
    "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:transactionRevenue"}, 
    {"expression":"ga:transactions"},{"expression":"ga:sessions"}],
    "dimensions" : [{"name": "ga:sourceMedium"},{"name":"ga:campaign"}]               
    }
   ],
   "useResourceQuotas": true,
  }
  var response = 
  AnalyticsReporting.Reports.batchGet(JSON.stringify(request));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on how the `response` from batchGet is formatted in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet);

Parse `response` as you will need to convert it into the format required by [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)); a two dimensional array matching the dimensions of a range specified on your spreadsheet (via sheet.getRange() ). i.e., following your above code,

```
outputArray = parseMyResponse(response);
sheet.getRange("A2:F").setValues(outputArray);
```

Comment: `"A2:F"` is not a desirable range to write an array to. Use the calculable size of `outputArray` to select the properly sized Range.

Comment: Yes, that is an option, especially if you need to insert ranges of arbitrary length. The above example is provided for an easy understanding of how to use .setValues();

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, however I cannot use setValues() on  response directly

Comment: Yes. As stated, you will need to parse `response` so that the values are an appropriate two-dimensional array which can be inserted into your spreadsheet.

Comment: I understand, however, I don't know what method to use to parse my response. I guess there's not a method like the one you wrote. If you were writing that data, what would you use?

Comment: You will need to write your own function to parse the data from what you receive to what you need.